# Validation String Prevention Not Working?

Tags: c#, string, validation

I'm trying to convert a number input by the user, the TryParse method isn't working and I'm hoping to make it not crash if the decimelPlacetxtBox text doesn't have a number in it either. By all logic it shouldn't crash as the code is correct but it still does, could anyone help me out. Maybe it's my noob brain but I just can't make sense of this

```
 private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int decimalPlace = int.Parse(decimelPlacetxtBox.Text);


        if (!double.TryParse(txtboxAmount.Text, out double amount) || !int.TryParse(decimelPlacetxtBox.Text, out int decimalPlaces)) return; // Prevents empty string, validation errorerror
        {
            double userInput = Convert.ToDouble(txtboxAmount.Text);

            // Killogram convertion

            if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "KG" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LB")
            {
                double conver = userInput * 2.20462262185;
                txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlace);
            }

            if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "KG")
            {
                double conver = userInput / 2.2046;
                txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlace);
            }

            if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ST" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "KG")
            {
                double conver = userInput * 6.35;
                txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlace);
            }

                // Pound convertion

                if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ST")
            {
                double conver = userInput / 14;
                txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlace);
            }

            if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ST" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LB")
            {
                double conver = userInput / 14;
                txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlace);
            }

            if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "KG")
            {
                double conver = userInput / 2.205;
                txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlace);
            }

            {
                comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem = -1;
            }

            // Stone convertion

            if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ST" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LB")
            {
                double conver = userInput * 14;
                txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlace);
            }

            if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ST")
            {
                double conver = userInput / 14;
                txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlace);
            }

            if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "KG")
            {
                double conver = userInput / 2.205;
                txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlace);


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: When it crashes, does any error messages appear? If so, what do they say?

Comment: It's okay I fixed it, I moved the  int decimalPlace = int.Parse(decimelPlacetxtBox.Text); line into the if statement